# React Server Side rendering: how can I know my component is mounted on the client side?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

**Note:** I'm using the beautiful library [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) though it should not impact the answer as far as I understand my problem.

---

I have a `<Component />` which loads a `<Map />`, which implies client-side rendering as it doesn't make sense on the server side (at least the lib I'm using doesn't do that).

So instead, I want to display an image before the clientside is ready, to apply the Skeuomorphism principle.

Basically, this means I have:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var content;
    if (this.state.clientSideReady) { // How can I change my component state here?
      content = <Map />
    } else {
      content = <PlaceholderImage />
    }
    return (<div>{content}</div>)
  }
});
```

From my current understanding, `componentDidMount` is called on the server-side, when the template string is generated. How can I know the component **actually** mounted on the clientside so I can replace my image by the actual map?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. As from this answer `componentDidMount` **isn't called** on the server-side.

So I can go:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      clientSideReady: false
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      clientSideReady: true
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var content;
    if (this.state.clientSideReady) { 
      content = <Map />
    } else {
      content = <PlaceholderImage />
    }
    return (<div>{content}</div>)
  }
});
```